# Missing \begin{document} error with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, pdftex, miktex2.9

I am having trouble using pgfplots. I reinstalled my MikTeX 2.9 version because something broke. It's working fine, but when I try to use `\usepackage{pgfplots}` with pdfLaTeX I get the following:

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `pgf',
               but the package provides `['.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13 \ProvidesPackageRCS[v
                          \pgfversion] $Header: /cvsroot/pgf/pgf/latex/pgf/b...

?
```

I have a MWE below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I have made sure to update MikTeX and all the packages so I'm quite sure that's not the issue.

UPDATE: I have also tried the same code on a different machine and the problem persists.

Comment: It is very strange. Have you checked other package, like `pgfplots`'s mother `tikz`, or common packages like `amsmath`?

Comment: Do you have a version of `pgfplots` somewhere outside the ordinary MiKTeX directories? Delete it.

Comment: Did you update as user *and* as admin?

Comment: Is the code snippet that you posted exactly the same that you're trying? Because I get no error with it.